# What means "(digital) meshware" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, technical-terminology

I read [this appeal](https://www.iab.org/wp-content/IAB-uploads/2015/06/20150622-IANAPLAN-Appeal-IAB.pdf) and try to transport the idea to my collegues. *(Digital) Meshware* is not a well known English word in Germany. I can describe what it means in German, but I need a self-explaining word for reference.

> A digital meshware or meshware (“relationnel” in French) is any set of rules, references, parameters and services that allow two or more networked nodes to interoperate between them via any kind of exchange protocol over a data link connecting them. Interoperating computer meshware contrasts with computer software, which is any set of machine-readable instructions that directs a digital processor to perform specific operations, and computer hardware, which is the physical component of computers.

What I think about:

- ***Verbundmaschine*** (Maschine shall transport the imagination of non-software, even if the microcontroller have their own "software")

Any further suggestions?

Comment: "Maschine" sounds like hardware, though.

Comment: In any case, you probably won't need a translation for "meshware" at all. "Hardware" and "Software" are exclusively used without translation, too (I don't know if it even exists).

Comment: *Verbundmaschine* is already taken. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleichstrommaschine#Verbundmaschine

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of the explanation of the word meshware I suggest to use any kind of words related to "Netzwerk".
This word has several meanings like personal networks (e.g. colleagues, friends, business partner), real hardwarerelated networks (e.g. LAN, WLAN) or digital networks (e.g. company domains).

A second interpretation is "Schnittstelle". As the explanation describes two single operating nodes communicating with each other and sharing services etc. it could possibly also be a "Schnittstelle".

(I have not read the whole document, if I've missed something please tell me.)